# is it possible to include # in redirect_uri for facebook's dialog/feed

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, share

I have a jquery mobile site that I want to share via facebook's dialog/feed system.

jQuery mobile uses *#*'s for their internal navigation system, so if I want to share a jqm url for page_3 of my jqm site, I would use something like: http://www.my_jqm_site.com/#page_3.

But that *#* is causing grief for facebook's dialog/feed:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed
  ?app_id       = ...
  &link         = http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/#page_3
  &redirect_uri = http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/#page_3
  &picture      = ...
  &name         = .
  &caption      = ...
  &description  = ...
```

So is their anyway to do it?

I have tried it both with and without encoding.

Currently I suppose I will use a *?* and then get the page to make some alterations via javascript during loading, but I really hate the thought of doing it this way.

Comment: It's not possible to do so on jQuery Mobile because of its built-in navigation using Ajax.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding your url?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in the post ... I added it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a problem like this right now. The URL to go in redirect_uri and link:

```
.../xfile.jsp?item=/contests/bhg_homeimprovement/bhg_splashsweeps_win2500_homeimprovement&temp=yes&hid=#HashID#&esrc=nwbhgsweeps072514a
```

The FB dialog gets an error as is. Encoding the full URL fixes that and does output hashes around "HashID", but the equal sign before it is removed. Adding a 2nd equal sign there will output 2 equal signs, but having just one will output none.

This isn't a complete solution but it does look like hash marks are possible.